# Trying to move object in assembly 8086

Tags: animation, assembly, x86-16

I want to move a char in row (initially row = 0) and if the row is 50 it will stop. But it is not working as expected.
Maybe it is not working due to `lea dx` and the fact that the row value is in `dl`.

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    snake db ">$"
.code

main proc

     mov ax, @data
     mov ds, ax

     mov ah, 06h
     mov al, 0
     mov ch, 0
     mov cl, 0
     mov dh, 24
     mov dl, 79
     mov bh, 00001100b

     int 10h
     mov dl, 5

    lb1:
         mov ah, 02h
         mov bh, 0
         mov dh, 5


         int 10h
         inc dl

         lea dx, snake
         mov ah, 2
         int 21h

        cmp dl, 50

  jbe lb1

     mov ah, 4ch
     int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: `lea dx, snake` <-- You realize that you're overwriting the value of `dl` here? Also, `int 21h / ah=2` prints a single character whose _value_ is located in `dl`. Perhaps you meant to use `int 21h / ah=9`?

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the replay i made some changes and it at least it  work. but i made some changes in my question please take a look at this. sorry for taking your time i'm new to assembly

Comment: @michael 

[IMAGE](https://i.ibb.co/Cw7t4FZ/Capture.png) i want to move **-->** on screen but it change it position and move but it append **--** 25 times. i only want to move **-->**

Comment: Then you have to write a space character (`' '`) at the old position.

Comment: new to it can you please tell me how or any blog or ref ?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to move a char in row [ initial row = 0 ]and if the row is [ row = 50] it will stop

Are you aware that your program changes the column instead of the row?

---

> ```
> lea dx, snake
> mov ah, 2
> int 21h
> ```

The fact that the above code destroys your column in `DL` can be corrected in 2 ways:

.Preserve `DL` on the stack

```
push dx
lea  dx, snake
mov  ah, 09h
int  21h
pop  dx
```

.Don't destroy `DL` by using another output function

```
mov  cx, 1
mov  bh, 0
mov  al, '>'
mov  ah, 0Ah
int  10h
```

---

To get a sense of moving you need to remove the object at its old place:

```
lb1:
 mov  cx, 1
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  al, ' '   ;Remove at old place
 mov  ah, 0Ah
 int  10h

 inc  dl        ;Goto to new place (next column)
 mov  dh, 5     ;Row 5, Column in DL
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  10h

 mov  cx, 1
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  al, '>'   ;Show at new place
 mov  ah, 0Ah
 int  10h

 cmp  dl, 50
 jbe  lb1
```

Because everything will happen so fast, you won't actually see the movement! You'll need a pause after you've shown the object.

As a quick alternative I'll use waiting for a keystroke:

```
lb1:
 mov  cx, 1
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  al, ' '   ;Remove at old place
 mov  ah, 0Ah
 int  10h

 inc  dl        ;Goto to new place (next column)
 mov  dh, 5     ;Row 5, Column in DL
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  10h

 mov  cx, 1
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  al, '>'   ;Show at new place
 mov  ah, 0Ah
 int  10h

 mov  ah, 00h   ;Wait for a keystroke.
 int  16h

 cmp  dl, 50
 jbe  lb1
```